# Why there is a 4-pole RCD while the mains is single phase?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

We have just bought a house and when I look at the electrical switchboard, I see a 4-pole residual current detector (RCD) while the mains supply to the house is single phase? Any idea why this has been installed instead of a 2-pole one?

[image]

Comment: What makes you think the RCD is 4-pole? I think it is only 1-pole. I don't believe a trip interrupts the neutral (earthed conductor). You have only one hot phase and this RCD will interrupt it in the event of a trip.

Comment: From the diagram on the RCD it seems the neutral might just be passed right through or the breaker might also interrupt the neutral and so in that sense be a 2-pole RCD. There are three (hot) phase connections shown but they are all the one phase.

Comment: In the US the breakers only interrupt the phases and not the neutral so my first thought would be that the neutral (grounded conductor) bypasses the breakers but I don't know this for sure in this case.

Comment: Where is this, what city and country/

Comment: GFCI/RCD often interrupt the neutral.  Thus in a 3-phase distribution it has 4 throws.  Note that overcurrent devices typically do not have an overcurrent sensor on neutral even if they interrupt it.

Comment: How do you know you have single-phase service? It would not be surprising if you actually had three-phase service and each horizontal group of branch-circuit breakers was on a different phase. You have enough large loads (electric water heater and air conditioner for sure) that you’d likely be overloading a 40A single-phase service.

Answer (score 5):

Most likely that is what the electrician had on hand at the time.

I can't see any other reason to install a breaker intended for 3 phase in a box that would probably need replacing if the service was upgraded to 3 phase.

Comment: So is this RCD in fact capable of 3-phase circuit interruption?

Comment: Abosolutely. the horizontal lines are just the wires that connect N and L1 to the test button. (I found a clearer image on e-bay)

Comment: So does this breaker also interrupt the neutral current path?

Comment: it certainly looks that way. the diagram shows sets of 5 contacts, one is on 'N' and another connects the test button to N, the remaining three ad for L1,2,3

Answer (score 1):

A 4-pole residual current device (RCD) can be used to protect two single-phase circuits, provided that it is appropriately rated and designed for such use. In this configuration, each pair of poles on the 4-pole RCD is used to protect one single-phase circuit.

Here's how it typically works:

- The first pair of poles (pole 1 and pole 2) are used to protect one single-phase circuit. The live conductor (phase) of that circuit is connected to pole 1, and the neutral conductor is connected to pole 2.
- The second pair of poles (pole 3 and pole 4) are used to protect the other single-phase circuit. The live conductor (phase) of the second circuit is connected to pole 3, and its neutral conductor is connected to pole 4.

This setup allows both single-phase circuits to be monitored for any imbalance in current between the live and neutral conductors. If a ground fault or leakage current is detected in either circuit, the 4-pole RCD will disconnect both circuits simultaneously.